# I want to show each games title in its specific platform in the navbar(no one answered, I have shown the full error as an answer )

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-templates, django-context

I want to show each games title in its specific platform in the navbar by creating a GameManager with a function called 'show_pc_game' which will only show games whose platform is PC.

> This is my models.py:

```
class GameManager(models.Manager):
def show_pc_game(self):
    return self.filter(platform='PC')

class Platform(models.Model):
    PLATFORM_CHOICES = (
        ('PC', 'PC'),
        ('PS', 'playstation'),
        ('XBOX', 'Xbox'),
        ('Nintendo Switch', 'nintendo switch'),
    )
    title = models.CharField(max_length=15, choices=PLATFORM_CHOICES, verbose_name= 
    "platform")
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=100, unique=True)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "platform"
        verbose_name_plural = "platforms"

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

class Game(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    description = models.TextField()
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=100, unique=True)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to="images")
    platform = models.ManyToManyField(Platform)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "game"
        verbose_name_plural = "games"

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    objects = GameManager()
```

> my views.py:

```
def home(request):
    return render(request, 'blog/base.html')

class GameList(ListView):
    template_name = "blog/game.html"
    model = Game

class GameDetail(DetailView):
    template_name = "blog/game_detail.html"

class PlatformList(ListView):
    template_name = "blog/platform.html"
    model = Platform
```

I have used 'extends' in secondary html files so I have to apply changes only in 'base.html'

> And this is my context_processors.py for apply contextes:

```
from .models import Platform, Game

def add_variable_to_context(request):
    return {
        'platforms': Platform.objects.all(),
        'games': Game.objects.all(),
        'PC_games': Game.objects.show_pc_game(),
    }
```

> And my base.html:

```
    <li class="nav-item dropdown">
        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" data-bs-toggle="dropdown">Platform</a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            {% for platform in platforms %}
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#"> {{platform.title}} &raquo; </a>
                {% for pcgame in PC_games %}
                <ul class="submenu dropdown-menu">
                    <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">{{game.title}}</a></li>
                </ul>
                {% endfor %}
            </li>
            {% endfor %}
        </ul>
    </li>
```

when I reload browser I get an error: 'Manager' object has no attribute 'show_pc_game'

any suggest to fix this?

Comment: Can you include the traceback?

Comment: I do not know what exactly it is

Comment: The full error message from your console/log

Comment: I posted it as the answer because it was too long

Comment: @IainShelvington

Comment: i solved that problem now another problem occured :[

Comment: Field 'id' expected a number but got 'PC'.

Comment: The filter in show_pc_game should be `self.filter(platform__title='PC')`

Comment: thank you this time it didn't give me the error but the result is not thing that I want.

Comment: {% for platform in platforms %}
        <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#"> {{platform.title}} &raquo; </a>
     {% for pcgame in PC_games %}
     <ul class="submenu dropdown-menu">
                <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">{{pcgame.title}}</a></li>
     </ul>
     {% endfor %}
 </li>
{% endfor %}

Comment: All games are shown for all platforms but i want to show it as this filter